# response method not exist in DioExceptionType in Dio package in flutter

Tags: flutter, http

**Hello World ,**
in last version of **dio** package `^5.4.0` , the DioExceptionType class didn't have a response method.
this code is before update

```
    switch (dioError.type) {
      case DioErrorType.connectTimeout:
        return ServerFailure("connectoin timeout with ApiServer");
      case DioErrorType.sendTimeout:
        return ServerFailure("Send timeout with ApiServer");

      case DioErrorType.receiveTimeout:
        return ServerFailure("receive timeout with ApiServer");
      case DioErrorType.response:
        return ServerFailure.fromResponse(
            dioError.response!.statusCode!, dioError.response!.data);
      case DioErrorType.cancel:
        return ServerFailure("Request to ApiServer was canceled");
      case DioErrorType.other:
        if(dioError.message.contains('SocketException')){
          return ServerFailure("no Internel Connection");
        }
        return ServerFailure("Unexpected Error, Please try again");
        default:
          return ServerFailure('Opps There was an Error, Please try again');
    }
  }
```

in new update code

```
  factory ServerFailure.fromDioError(DioException dioError){
    switch (dioError.type) {
      case DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout:
        return ServerFailure("connectoin timeout with ApiServer");
      case DioExceptionType.sendTimeout:
        return ServerFailure("Send timeout with ApiServer");

      case DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout:
        return ServerFailure("receive timeout with ApiServer");
      case DioExceptionType.response:
        return ServerFailure.fromResponse(
            dioError.response!.statusCode!, dioError.response!.data);
      case DioExceptionType.cancel:
        return ServerFailure("Request to ApiServer was canceled");
      case DioErrorType.other:
        if(dioError.message!.contains('SocketException')){
          return ServerFailure("no Internel Connection");
        }
        return ServerFailure("Unexpected Error, Please try again");
        default:
          return ServerFailure('Opps There was an Error, Please try again');
    }
  }
```

I have tow errors in this code.

- `There's no constant named 'response' in 'DioExceptionType'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing constant, or defining a constant named 'response'.` in 22 line.
- `There's no constant named 'other' in 'DioExceptionType'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing constant, or defining a constant named 'other'` in 27 line.
  **note:** those two errors was not exist before last update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DioErrorType` has different values in the latest release (5.x).

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| response | badResponse |
| other | unknown |

See [Migration Guide](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/topics/Migration%20Guide-topic.html#500) for details.